How to set data to the odata model in sapui5?
I'm using an analytical table in my project, binding it directly to the table with oTable.bindRows(oTableBinding). However, I'm not utilizing the ODataModel.read operation. How can I set data to this OData model (similar to a JSON model) to bind it to the table in SAPUI5?
Below is my code:
var oTableBinding = new sap.ui.model.analytics.AnalyticalBinding(oModel, spath, fecBindcontext, [], [], oBindingParams);
oTable.bindRows(oTableBinding);

I want to add JSON data to this table. Due to OData model binding, I'm unable to set this data to the model.
Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.
